# ElasticSearch Laravel scout exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, full-text-search, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to implement Laravel Scout and ElasticSearch. I am having these 2 challenges: when I run tinker on the cmd thus it gives this output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\blacapollo>php artisan scout:import "App\Albums"
Imported [App\Albums] models up to ID: 2
All [App\Albums] records have been imported.
C:\xampp\htdocs\blacapollo>php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.0.8 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> App/Albums::search('come and')->get();
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Albums' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
>>>
```

I thought maybe it's something that could be bypassed, so I proceeded to write the controller and view following this tutorial - [Basic Search Functionality with ElasticSearch & Laravel Scout](https://medium.com/@samogorm/basic-search-functionality-with-elasticsearch-laravel-scout-6ac182c99cbf#.t7yc7nwhb)

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $searchedSongs = '';
       if($request->has('search')){

          $searchedSongs = Songs::search($request->input('search'))->get();
       }
       return view('search.results')->with('searchedSongs', $searchedSongs);
    }
```

Blade form:

```
<form id="elasticScout" action="/SearchQuery" method="get">
     <div class="mysearchbar">
         <input name="search" placeholder="Search...">
     </div>
</form>

@if(!empty($searchedSongs))
    @foreach($searchedSongs as $searchedSong)
        <h1>{{ $searchedSong->originalName }} </h1>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

When I access the view and tried searching a query, an existing model it returns this error:

```
BadRequest400Exception in Connection.php line 682:
parsing_exception: no [query] registered for [filtered]
in Connection.php line 682
at Connection->tryDeserializeError(array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}'), 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception') in Connection.php line 659
at Connection->tryDeserialize400Error(array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}')) in Connection.php line 579
at Connection->process4xxError(array('http_method' => 'GET', 'scheme' => 'http', 'uri' => '/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'body' => '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":[],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"come","fuzziness":1}}}]}}}}}', 'headers' => array('host' => array('localhost:9200'))), array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}'), array()) in Connection.php line 261
at Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}')) in FulfilledPromise.php line 25
at FulfilledPromise->then(object(Closure), null, null) in CompletedFutureValue.php line 55
at CompletedFutureValue->then(object(Closure), null, null) in Core.php line 341
at Core::proxy(object(CompletedFutureArray), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 282
at Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(array('http_method' => 'GET', 'scheme' => 'http', 'uri' => '/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'body' => '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":[],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"come","fuzziness":1}}}]}}}}}', 'headers' => array('host' => array('localhost:9200'))), object(Connection), object(Transport), array()) in Connection.php line 159
at Connection->performRequest('GET', '/scout/songs/_search', array('size' => '10000'), '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":[],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"come","fuzziness":1}}}]}}}}}', array(), object(Transport)) in Transport.php line 100
at Transport->performRequest('GET', '/scout/songs/_search', array('size' => '10000'), array('query' => array('filtered' => array('filter' => array(), 'query' => array('bool' => array('must' => array(array('match' => array('_all' => array('query' => 'come', 'fuzziness' => '1'))))))))), array()) in Client.php line 1345
at Client->performRequest(object(Search)) in Client.php line 849
at Client->search(array('size' => '10000')) in ElasticsearchEngine.php line 209
at ElasticsearchEngine->performSearch(object(Builder), array('filters' => array(), 'size' => '10000')) in ElasticsearchEngine.php line 109
at ElasticsearchEngine->search(object(Builder)) in Engine.php line 70
at Engine->get(object(Builder)) in Builder.php line 149
at Builder->get() in SearchController.php line 24
at SearchController->search(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SearchController), 'search'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('search', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(SearchController), 'search') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\blacapollo\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
1/2
BadRequest400Exception in Connection.php line 681:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}
in Connection.php line 681
at Connection->tryDeserializeError(array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}'), 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception') in Connection.php line 659
at Connection->tryDeserialize400Error(array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}')) in Connection.php line 579
at Connection->process4xxError(array('http_method' => 'GET', 'scheme' => 'http', 'uri' => '/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'body' => '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":[],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"come","fuzziness":1}}}]}}}}}', 'headers' => array('host' => array('localhost:9200'))), array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}'), array()) in Connection.php line 261
at Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'http_code' => '400', 'header_size' => '96', 'request_size' => '205', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0.016', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '114', 'size_download' => '227', 'speed_download' => '14187', 'speed_upload' => '7125', 'download_content_length' => '227', 'upload_content_length' => '114', 'starttransfer_time' => '0.016', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '9200', 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => '6969', 'error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => '0'), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost:9200/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'headers' => array('content-type' => array('application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'content-length' => array('227')), 'version' => '1.1', 'status' => '400', 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}')) in FulfilledPromise.php line 25
at FulfilledPromise->then(object(Closure), null, null) in CompletedFutureValue.php line 55
at CompletedFutureValue->then(object(Closure), null, null) in Core.php line 341
at Core::proxy(object(CompletedFutureArray), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 282
at Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(array('http_method' => 'GET', 'scheme' => 'http', 'uri' => '/scout/songs/_search?size=10000', 'body' => '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":[],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"come","fuzziness":1}}}]}}}}}', 'headers' => array('host' => array('localhost:9200'))), object(Connection), object(Transport), array()) in Connection.php line 159
at Connection->performRequest('GET', '/scout/songs/_search', array('size' => '10000'), '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":[],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"come","fuzziness":1}}}]}}}}}', array(), object(Transport)) in Transport.php line 100
at Transport->performRequest('GET', '/scout/songs/_search', array('size' => '10000'), array('query' => array('filtered' => array('filter' => array(), 'query' => array('bool' => array('must' => array(array('match' => array('_all' => array('query' => 'come', 'fuzziness' => '1'))))))))), array()) in Client.php line 1345
at Client->performRequest(object(Search)) in Client.php line 849
at Client->search(array('size' => '10000')) in ElasticsearchEngine.php line 209
at ElasticsearchEngine->performSearch(object(Builder), array('filters' => array(), 'size' => '10000')) in ElasticsearchEngine.php line 109
at ElasticsearchEngine->search(object(Builder)) in Engine.php line 70
at Engine->get(object(Builder)) in Builder.php line 149
at Builder->get() in SearchController.php line 24
at SearchController->search(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SearchController), 'search'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('search', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(SearchController), 'search') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\blacapollo\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Are you using ES 5 by any chance? The `filtered` query has been deprecated.

Comment: I'm running Version:5.0.1

Comment: There you go. any chance to use ES 2.4 instead?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `App\Albums::search('come and')->get();` instead.

The correct way to implement a namespace is with a backward slash `\` and not a forward slash `/`.

Comment: Hi! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is necessary to clear the cache

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I hope it works for you too